# How to iterate over columns and connacenate two columns into one

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
               Border #1 [from] Border #1 [to]  Border #2 [from] Border #2 [to]
index                                                                  
0                   BE           BE_AL                 PL              SK
1                   BE           BE_AL                 PL              SK
```

And I want to connect every two columns into one (I have many more columns), the desired result:

```
                   Border #1                Border #2
index                                                                  
0                   BE_BE_AL                 PL_SK
1                   BE_BE_AL                 PL_SK
```

For one column I could do:

```
df['Border#1']=df['Border #1 [from]']+'_'+df['Border #1 [to]']
```

but how can I do it for multiple columns?

Comment: post your dataframe as code so we can copy it into our IDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `MutliIndex` by split by `[` with space, so possible select both levels by [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) and join by `+`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip(']').str.split('\s+\[', expand=True)
print (df)
  Border #1        Border #2    
       from     to      from  to
0        BE  BE_AL        PL  SK
1        BE  BE_AL        PL  SK

print (df.columns)
MultiIndex([('Border #1', 'from'),
            ('Border #1',   'to'),
            ('Border #2', 'from'),
            ('Border #2',   'to')],
           )

df = df.xs('from', axis=1, level=1) +'_'+ df.xs('to', axis=1, level=1)
print (df)
  Border #1 Border #2
0  BE_BE_AL     PL_SK
1  BE_BE_AL     PL_SK
```

Answer (score 2):

You can group the columns and craft a new dataframe

```
groups = df.columns.str.replace(' \[.+\]', '', regex=True)
df2 = pd.concat({g: d.apply('_'.join, axis=1)
                 for g,d in df.groupby(groups, axis=1)}, axis=1)
```

output:

```
      Border #1 Border #2
index                    
0      BE_BE_AL     PL_SK
1      BE_BE_AL     PL_SK
```

Answer (score 0):

groupby axis=1 and join the columns

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    return dd.agg("_".join,axis=1)

df1.groupby(df1.columns.str[8],axis=1).apply(function1).add_prefix(df1.columns.max()[:8])
```

out：

```
    Border #1 Border #2
index                    
0      BE_BE_AL     PL_SK
1      BE_BE_AL     PL_SK
```